# Type of panda.Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
data = pandas.read_csv("weather_data.csv")

print(data)
print(data[data['day'] == 'Monday'])
print(type(data['day']))
print(type(data['day'] == 'Monday'))
```

output

```
         day  temp condition
0     Monday    12     Sunny
1    Tuesday    14      Rain
2  Wednesday    15      Rain
3   Thursday    14    Cloudy
4     Friday    21     Sunny
5   Saturday    22     Sunny
6     Sunday    24     Sunny
      day  temp condition
0  Monday    12     Sunny
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I'm a bit confused about the last output. How come `data['day'] == 'Monday'` returns a `panda.Series` and why the index of `data` can be a `panda.Series`?

Comment: Why does that confuse you? What were you *expecting* `data['day'] == 'Monday'` to return???

Comment: If compare `Series` by scalar (or another Series) get boolen Series, it is expected ouput.  `data[data['day'] == 'Monday']` is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and filter rows by boolean mask - returned rows matched mask (so return rows if Trues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [DataFrame](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe) is a collection of aligned [Series](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series/), aligned means that all Series are labeled in the same manner. The common part or labels is called [Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) and it is nothing more than a pimped Serie.

Operations with Series tend to return a Serie itself, easily it is an element-wise comparison, the result is an array of boolean of the same size and with the same labels a boolean array, called [*mask*](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html).

#### some example:

```
import pandas as pd
ds1 = pd.Series([2, 4, 6])
ds2 = pd.Series([1, 4, 7])

print(ds1)
print(type(ds1))

# out

0    2
1    4
2    6
dtype: int64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Playing with masks:

```
dseq = ds1 == ds2

print(dseq)
print(type(dseq))

# out

0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

This works for all comparison:

```
print(ds1 > ds2)
print(ds1 < ds2)
print(ds1 >= ds2)

#out

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```